# Trying to access values from nodes to render in email template using swift mailer

Tags: php, email, drupal, theming

I'm currently working on trying to build an email html template using [swift mailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer). My problem right now is how can I customize the template to fetch the values from the nodes and render them in the email template. Fetch and print/render the node values only from the nodes that will be sent as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Swift mailer has a default way to output the values from all the fields using `{{ body }}`

Is there a way I could access the values from the fields and render them on the template. Something like the code below that works on node template

`{{content.field_title.value}}` or `{{node.field_title.value}}`

Swift mailer has a way to render values via preprocess but I can't seem to make it work. Below is the code that is a work in progress

> https://www.drupal.org/node/1590184

```
function swiftmailer_preprocess_swiftmailer(&$variables) {
    $variables['node_title'] = $node->getTitle();
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the node to the swiftmailer. With simplenews or ...? Please try to var_dump variables and check what inside. The preprocess is the right thing to do.

Comment: @shaxaaa actually haven't figured it out yet to pass the node to the swiftmailer. I'm still a beginner so things like `preprocess` I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Is it always the content of one node. I am not sure what you need to develop.

Comment: @shaxaaa yes, it is the content of one node

Answer (score 2):

```
function swiftmailer_preprocess_swiftmailer(&$variables) {
    // Don't forget to use the Node class on top of your .module or .theme file.
    $node = Node::load(YourNodeId); // Here add your node id. If you don't want it to be hardcoded I would suggest you to create a config page for it. The other way is to put a checkbox in it and then find it here with a query.
    $variables['node_title'] = $node->getTitle();
}
```

After you do this in your swiftmailer.html.twig you will be able to render the node title like so {{ node_title }}

Answer (score 0):

@clestcruz, Preprocess is good option for this. But You can create service as well for this.

Create custom module named as `foo` .
Create all required files and then create `foo.services.yml` . 
mention service like :

```
services:
  foo.twig.TwigExtension:
    class: Drupal\foo\XYZ
    tags:
      - {name: twig.extension}
```

create service file in `foo/src/XYZ.php`

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\foo;
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Class DefaultService.
 *
 * @package Drupal\foo
 */
class XYZ extends \Twig_Extension {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * This function must return the name of the extension. It must be unique.
   */
  public function getName() {
    return 'product_listing_extend_display';
  }

  /**
   * In this function we can declare the extension function.
   */
  public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
      'getData' => new \Twig_Function_Method( $this, 'getData', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
    );
  }

// Function to get tax childs by tid
  function getData($id) {
    // query for data 
   // return value
  }

}
```

Call method {{ getData() }} in twig file.